# Splinter - How to click a link / button implemented as a div or span element

Tags: python, web-scraping, splinter

I am using the Splinter library in Python. I wish to click on a link according to the link text, but this is not working.

The link is included in the source like:

```
<a href="link here"><span style="color:#000000;">link text here</span></a>
```

Using '`browser.click_link_by_text('link text here')`' gives an error:

> splinter.exceptions.ElementDoesNotExist: no elements could be found
>   with link by text "link text here"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to use developer tools or Firebug to find the xpath of the element you are interested in and then use `find_by_xpath` based on that

```
from splinter import Browser

with Browser() as browser:
    browser.visit("http://www.thisamericanlife.org")
    browser.fill('keys', 'relationships')
    button = browser.find_by_xpath('/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/form/div/input[1]').click()
    print browser.url
```

This fills in the form (in this case for the search term "relationships") and then navigates to the page http://www.thisamericanlife.org/search?keys=relationships

Answer (score 6):

I have also stumbled onto `click_link_by_text` function several times, but succeeded with rest of the followings. You can try any of these.

```
browser.click_link_by_href('link here')          # From "link here"
browser.click_link_by_partial_href('link')       # From "link here"
browser.click_link_by_partial_text('link text')  # From "link text here"
```

You can follow the documentation here:
https://splinter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/driver-and-element-api.html#splinter.driver.DriverAPI.click_link_by_text

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide the complete code? I cannot say why it is not working for you because it works fine for me with the following code.

```
 from splinter import Browser

 browser = Browser('chrome')
 browser.visit("https://www.google.co.in/")
 browser.fill('q','facebook')
 button = browser.find_by_name('btnG')
 button.click()
 browser.click_link_by_text("Facebook Login")
```

Answer (score 0):

have a try ~~~~

```
from splinter import Browser
browser = Browser('chrome')
browser.windows.current = browser.windows[0] #maybe you have a lot of windows.
xpath = '//div[@class="big-play-button"]'
browser.find_by_xpath(xpath).click()
```

Comment: Ideally this would have some explanation along with the code.